# JSR303 i18n not working in Primefaces based page

Tags: java, primefaces, bean-validation

I am trying to customize (including i18n) JSR303 but I always get

```
### Message 'msg.test.validation' not found ###
```

I have created a ValidationMessages.properties file with content

```
msg.test.validation=This is a test
```

The files (including ValidationMessages_de.properties, _de_DE.properties and _en.properties) are placed in src/main/resources. In the war file the files are located at WEB-INF/classes (standard maven behaviour)

In the managed bean I have

```
@NotNull    
@Pattern (regexp="^[_A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$", message = "{msg.test.validation}")
private String test;
```

And the Primefaces 6.0 based page contains

```
<h:form>
  <p:inputText id="test" value="#{validationView.test}" label="Test" />
  <p:commandButton id="testbutton" action="#{validationView.showTest}"  value="Test" validateClient="true" />
  <p:message for="test" />
</h:form>
```

I seems the ValidationMessages are not found, but why? If I put a message instead of the placeholder 'msg.test.validation' this message is displayed.

Any hints?

Comment: found the reason, I have enabled `primefaces.CLIENT_SIDE_VALIDATION`. When disabled, the messages are found. But I still have not found a solution for keeping the property enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work within prime-faces component as:

```
<p:inputText validatorMessage="#{message['msg.test.validation']}" />
```

Comment: works, but message must not refer to ValidationMessage but to a messages.properties placed in the package folder. Not 100% what I want to do. E.g. I cannot include the field name using {0} what I can do in ValidationMessages file

Comment: I've had the same problem here. Solution is that won't work within primefaces client validation. If p:comandButton has clientValidation=true so the beanvalidation.js file won't have your customised message either. We disabled this feature and now a request is done in order to validate the property. File is ValidationMessages.properties in root of resources folder. For me was the simplest way which works.

Comment: Yes, you cannot include ordinal like {0} but you might as well using {max} , {min}  which are bean validation parameters.

Comment: For me the client validation is more important than the field name to be mentioned. So I am now using the above solution.